# A problem in apply_async in multiprocess pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

I'm using multiprocessing pool in Python and its `.apply_async()` method to run several workers as concurrent.

But there is a problem due to using `with` instead of creating an instance arbitrary.

Here's what I've done so far:

---

### Common section code snippet:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep, time

def worker(x):
    print(f"{x} started.")
    sleep(x)
    print(f"{x} finished.")
    return f"{x} finished."

result_list = []
def log_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)
```

---

### First code snippet which works well through the *Python 2* manner:

```py
tick = time()

pool = Pool()
for i in range(6):
    pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i, ), callback=log_result)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print('Total elapsed time: ', time() - tick)
print(result_list)
print(i)  # Indicates that all iteration has been done.
```

Out:

```
1 started.
2 started.
0 started.
0 finished.
3 started.
4 started.
1 finished.
5 started.
2 finished.
3 finished.
4 finished.
5 finished.
Total elapsed time:  6.022687673568726
['0 finished.', '1 finished.', '2 finished.', '3 finished.', '4 finished.', '5 finished.']
5
```

---

### Second code snippet which works well through the *Python 3* manner:

```py
tick = time()

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(6):
        executor.submit(worker, i)

print('Total elapsed time: ', time() - tick)
print(i)  # Indicates that all iteration has been done.
```

Out:

```
0 started.
0 finished.
1 started.
2 started.
3 started.
4 started.
1 finished.
5 started.
2 finished.
3 finished.
4 finished.
5 finished.
Total elapsed time:  6.017550945281982
5
```

Extra:

- An infer might be obtained that the *Python 3* manner is faster than *Python 2* method.

---

## Question:

Now the problem is here which I want to implement the *Python 2* manner using `with` such as *Python 3* method, but tasks not completed:

```py
tick = time()

with Pool() as pool:
    for i in range(6):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=log_result)

print('Total elapsed time: ', time() - tick)
print(result_list)
print(i)  # Indicates that all iteration has been done.
```

Out:

```
Total elapsed time:  0.10628008842468262
[]
5
```

However, If I placed a `sleep(1)` after `pool.apply_async(...)` some lite tasks will be finished (establishing a block):

```py
tick = time()

with Pool() as pool:
    for i in range(6):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=log_result)
        sleep(1)

print('Total elapsed time: ', time() - tick)
print(result_list)
print(i)  # Indicates that all iteration has been done.
```

Out:

```
0 started.
0 finished.
1 started.
2 started.
1 finished.
3 started.
4 started.
2 finished.
5 started.
3 finished.
Total elapsed time:  6.022568702697754
['0 finished.', '1 finished.', '2 finished.', '3 finished.']
5
```

---

What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concurrent.futures.Executor` and `multiprocessing.Pool` have two completely different [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) implementations.

`concurrent.futures.Executor` calls `shutdown(wait=True)` effectively waiting for all enqueued jobs to finish as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown).

> You can avoid having to call this method explicitly if you use the with statement, which will shutdown the Executor (waiting as if Executor.shutdown() were called with wait set to True)

`multiprocessing.Pool` calls `terminate` instead of `close` and then `join` which leads to premature interruption of all ongoing jobs. In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join).

> Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. **enter**() returns the pool object, and **exit**() calls terminate().

If you want to use `multiprocessing.Pool` together with its context manager, you need to wait for the results yourself.

```
with Pool() as pool:
    async_result = pool.apply_async(worker, args=(i,), callback=log_result)
    async_result.wait()
```

Comment: sorry, i write new code like above,but it didn't work